# Refinitiv list of stock symbol

Tags: excel, stock, refinitiv-eikon-api, refinitiv-eikon

I am using Excel stock data in Mac and able to find the stock/mutual fund symbols. I understand stock data is coming from "Refinitiv".

I am not able to find the Mutual fund "Axis Nifty IT Index Fund" in the excel. Also, i am trying to find this mutual fund is listed in "Refinitiv".

How/where to find the list of stocks/mutual fund which Refinitiv has currently?